# Why error No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2

Tags: java, spring, mule, h2, mulesoft

When I debug my Mule application i have error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error retrieving database metadata; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:~/test
```

my java code:

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).withProcedureName("my_procedure_name").withSchemaName("my_schema");
...
call.execute(in)
```

my aaplicationContext:

```
<bean id="dataSource2"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db2.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db2.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db2.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db2.password}" />
</bean>
```

my app_name.properties:

```
db2.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
db2.driver=org.h2.Driver
db2.user=sa
db2.password=
```

my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
```

my classpath:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/h2database/h2/1.4.200/h2-1.4.200.jar"/>
```

log info after run application:

```
INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
```

Also i put h2-1.4.200.jar (when I starting my application from AnypointStudio) to:

```
c:\...\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.9.0_6.4.0.201908221250\mule\lib\user\ 
and:
c:\...\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.9.0_6.4.0.201908221250\mule\lib\boot\ 
and:
c:\...\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.9.0_6.4.0.201908221250\mule\lib\mule\
```

and when I run application from mule server h2-1.4.200.jar, I put here:

```
..\mule-standalone-3.9.0\lib\boot
and
..\mule-standalone-3.9.0\lib\user
and:
..\mule-standalone-3.9.0\lib\mule
```

why application driver h2 not found ? what's the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean it is only failing when debugging in Anypoint Studio? Does it work when just running, in Studio or in Standalone?

Comment: not works in debug, not works also when i running in Studio or in standalone. ... just in debug mode more I can see what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing 3 different ways of managing the JDBC driver dependency, and also duplicating the library in the runtimes. That also makes it more difficult to understand the problem, and to deploy an application.

Let's start with Maven. It looks like you are using the right dependency in the pom, as long as it is in the  section.

If the project is using Maven, there should not be any need to look into , unless it is out of sync with Maven. You should not change the class path manually, or edit the build path in Anypoint Studio. These are part of Studio/Eclipse .classpath files and should be left alone. Be sure to update the project so Studio regenerates the classpath.

About MULE_HOME\lib\boot, MULE_HOME\lib\user, MULE_HOME\lib\mule (either in Studio or standalone), you should not put the library in there. The Maven dependency is enough and you are duplicating the versions. Even if you can share a library in lib\user, it is not recommended. It makes more difficult to replicate sanely a deployment and again, there is no need for the JDBC driver. You should not put anything at all in lib\boot nor lib\mule nor the other subdirectories of lib. These are reserved for the runtime.

Try removing all those extras first and see what happens with a clean deployment.

Update:

Once the libraries are cleaned up, take into account that the Spring class may have some [classloading issues](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) itself. It is almost always better to use a datasource pool implementation. There are several to choose, like c3p0, dbcp, and others.

One example with c3p0:

```
<spring:bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <spring:property name="driverClass" value="${JDBC.driver}"/>
  <spring:property name="jdbcUrl" value="${JDBC.URL}"/>
  <spring:property name="user" value="${JDBC.user}"/>
  <spring:property name="password" value="${JDBC.password}"/>
  <spring:property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
  <spring:property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
</spring:bean>
```

See https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Spring-based-datasources for more examples.

Comment: I duplicated library only for testing . Now I removed library from directories: /opt /boot / and /user but still I have the same error:
 "Error retrieving database metadata; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:~/test"

Comment: I am not changed or edited classpath. I updated project in Studio ( Mule -> Update project dependencies) but still I have the same error.

Comment: maybe problem is in the datasource2 bean property name "driverClassName". I use org.springframework 4.3.17.RELEASE .

Comment: I see it with the same name in some old projects I found.

Comment: But the problem could be in DriverManagerDataSource. Its javadocs stats that it may have classloading issues, like this. It is almost always better to use a pool datasource implementation. I'll update my answer.

Comment: it works but only dataSource: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource . Thanks